# how to register anonymous HealthIndicators in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

This link [writing_custom_healthindicators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_writing_custom_healthindicators) describes how to register custom `HealthIndicators` so that they can be used with Spring Boot Actuator.  The example in the link uses `@Component` to register custom classes that implement the `HealthIndicator` interface.

But I am creating anonymous `HealthIndicator` instances.  Below is an example of how these anonymous `HealthIndicators` instances can be created.

```
        HealthIndicator healthIndicator = () -> {
            Health h;
            //custom code to instantiate Health object.
            return h;
        };
        //how to register h with Spring?
```

Lets say the code above is in a for loop where many `HealthIndicators` are being created.  How can they be registered with Spring so that Spring Boot Actuator recognizes them as mentioned in the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to provide custom [`HealthEndpoint`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/HealthEndpoint.html) like so:

```
@Configuration
class HealthConfig {
    @Bean
    HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint(Map<String, HealthIndicator> defaultIndicators){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i+=1){
            defaultIndicators.put("custom_indicator_" + i, ()-> Health.down().build());
        }
        return new HealthEndpoint(new OrderedHealthAggregator(), defaultIndicators);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  Will try this today.